# Are there enough new questions coming in?

Tags: discussion

When looking at the list of questions on main from the "newest" tab and scrolling back in time, it seems to me (without extracting statistics), that there are hardly 5 new questions coming in each day (not only at weekends).

On Area51 it is said that 15 new questions per day on average are needed for a healthy Beta ...

So are there currently enough new questions coming in here on Astronomy?

Comment: Ok, now I have found the (negative ...) answer [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40709/astronomy), stupid me ... So I will probably delete this meta quetion soon, as a more appropriate question would be to ask what can be done about these worrysome statistics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I saw a typical curve that successful SE sites follow for questions and visits. It starts with a big surge, then dives to a low point, and then gradually recovers until it reaches healthy levels.

Unsuccessful sites probably just keep going down until they hit near zero before they get closed.

So far, it looks like Astronomy could go either way. So go out and spread the news, quickly before the site dies.

Comment: Do you think it is time to ring some kind of warning bell ... :-/? There seems to be a bit more activity right now though and a new expert in cosmology has joined and nicely answered my two questions :-)

Comment: Things will pick up again, it just goes in phases as Donald suggests, have seen it on several betas